# Mod rewrite to reidrect all traffic to different domain, except for set list of folders

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, configuration

We are gradually moving a clients site to a new system & domain name.
In the meantime we need both sites live - but sharing bits of the same domain.

I have now pointed the primary domain to the new server - www.newserver.org

On this server I need Apache to redirect any requests not in a list of allowable folders back to the old server - now living on: www.oldserver.org (preserving the path after the domain).

I also need the new server to be accessible without redirecting when accessed via it's IP address.

My best attempt at the apache configuration:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/landing/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/scripts/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.newserver.org$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)  http://www.oldserver.org/$1  [NC,R=301,L]
```

Can anyone assist with the right RewriteCond & ordering?
At the moment all requests - even to the specified folders are redirecting.

---- also tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.newserver.org$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(landing|admin|user|sites|scripts) [NC]
RewriteRule   ^(.*)  http://www.oldserver.org/$1  [NC,R=301,L]
```

suggested on another forum but this is still redirecting all requests - even to those folders

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.newserver.org$
RewriteRule ^(?!(landing|admin|user|sites|scripts)/)(\w+/.*)$   http://www.oldserver.org/$2 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. No luck sadly - redirects nothing at all with this variation.

Comment: what is the URL for testing? (Did you replace the domain name for the actual ones before testing?). Are you using something like `http://www.newserver.org/admin/` and then `http://www.newserver.org/administer/`? The first one should not redirect, the second one should redirect to www.oldserver.org/administer/. If you are using the IP address, no redirect should happen.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check for `HTTP_HOST`, unless both domains are served by the same system.

You are missing the leading slash, when checking for `REQUEST_URI`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(landing|admin|user|sites|scripts) [NC]
```